# How to include csjdbc.jar as part of maven dependency?

Tags: maven, jdbc

I have been looking for a dependency for csjdbc.jar in Maven repository so that I can build my app using maven and retrieve that jar on the fly. However, I cannot find a dependency in Maven repository related to that jar. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: did you mean this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.csvjdbc/csvjdbc/1.0.28

Comment: No, i don't think that's the one. That is for csv jdbc and not cs (composite).

Comment: can you should me the link of your jar please?

Comment: not sure what you meant by link. But here is my connection info:
jdbc:compositesw:dbapi@server:port

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have already resolved this issue.

csjdbc.jar is not listed in maven repositories. If you have composite software installed you can copy the jar from

> ~\Composite Software\CIS 6.1.0\apps\jdbc\lib

directory to your local machine's maven repository like below with proper versioning:

> C:\maven\repository\composite\csjdbc\6.1\csjdbc-6.1.jar

(I have 6.1 jar)